# ssh timeout error while training a deep learning model on GCP VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, deep-learning

I am trying to train a deep learning model on GCP VM which is supposed to run 10-12 hours. But every time it runs for few epoch (few hours), it gives ssh timeout error.
I have set the following parameters on the config file but still the same error. 
 Can this be a code issue or something to do with VM config parameter.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to understand the problem, then select the solution.

When you create an SSH connection to a host (your VM), this opens a TCP connection on port 22. The SSH server then runs a shell program in this SSH session. When the SSH session closes or is interrupted, the shell program is killed, which kills most processes that the shell started.

Home Internet providers often reset long-running connections. This is to prevent you from running servers or large downloads over a home Internet connection. There are other reasons that the Internet provider might reset connections that are normal. You need to understand that this will happen and select options to manage this.

There are several programs that are available. Look into [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) and [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

I use both programs and prefer tmux. Both programs are free and very popular. There are additional methods and programs from running your program in the background `&` to using `nohup`.

**From Wikipedia:**

tmux is a terminal multiplexer for Unix-like operating systems. It allows multiple terminal sessions to be accessed simultaneously in a single window. It is useful for running more than one command-line program at the same time. It can also be used to detach processes from their controlling terminals, allowing SSH sessions to remain active without being visible.

GNU Screen is a terminal multiplexer, a software application that can be used to multiplex several virtual consoles, allowing a user to access multiple separate login sessions inside a single terminal window, or detach and reattach sessions from a terminal. It is useful for dealing with multiple programs from a command line interface, and for separating programs from the session of the Unix shell that started the program, particularly so a remote process continues running even when the user is disconnected.